# Perl, input lines from Csv into a system command issues with reading whole csv

Tags: perl

I'm able to run the command now but its only reading the first line of the csv for now I only have to columns like this.

```
name,ipaddr
Athens_GA_VRoom,151.110.32.30
Belmond_IA_VRoom,151.110.33.250
```

it only does the first line with IP the second it doesn't

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/bin/bash
#use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;



    my $filename = "ssg_test1.csv";
    open(INPUT, '<', $filename) or die "Cannot open $filename";
   my $line = <INPUT>;
        while ($line = <INPUT>)
        {

        chomp $line;
        push (@filename, $_);

        my @name = split(',', $line);
        my @ip = split(',', $line);
        my $node = $name[0];
        my $node1 = $ip[1];

        system ("mgmt_cli add generic-object create \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiGatewayPlain\" name \"$node\" ipaddr \"$node1\" thirdPartyEncryption \"True\" osInfo.osName \"Gaia\"
vpn.create \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiVpn\" vpn.owned-object.vpnClientsSettingsForGateway.create \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiVpnClientsSettingsForGateway\" vpn.
owned-object.vpnClientsSettingsForGateway.owned-object.endpointVpnClientSettings.create \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiEndpointVpnClientSettingsForGateway\" vpn.owned-object.vpnCli
entsSettingsForGateway.owned-object.endpointVpnClientSettings.owned-object.endpointVpnEnable \"True\" vpn.owned-object.ike.create \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiIke\" vpn.owned-obj
ect.sslNe.create \"com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiSslNetworkExtender\" vpn.owned-object.sslNe.owned-object.sslEnable \"False\" vpn.owned-object.sslNe.owned-object.gwCertificate \"def
aultCert\" vpn.owned-object.isakmpUniversalSupport \"True\"");



}
    close (INPUT);
```

Comment: `@name` and `@ip` are populated with the same values. `print(system)` calls `system` with no arguments which fails and `print` then prints the non-zero exit code.

Comment: I've edited your question to format your input file so it's easier to understand how it looks. You're welcome, of course, but you might want to do it yourself next time. If you're asking a large group of people to read your code and help you, then you should make it as easy as possible for them.

Comment: Also, you populate `$line` before entering the loop, but then immediately overwrite the value with the following line. Is that expected?

Comment: Sorry the Print system was just for me to see the output, the commands runs but only creates the first line

Answer (score 0):

To debug this I replaced your big `system()` call with the line:

```
print "$node / $node1\n";
```

And I get the following output:

```
Athens_GA_VRoom / 151.110.32.30
Belmond_IA_VRoom / 151.110.33.250
```

So it **is** processing all of the lines in your input file. I'm not sure why you're not seeing that.

A few other tips that might help you.

- Having a shell shebang line as well as the Perl one is pointless and confusing.
- Don't comment out `use strict` (it's telling you that you haven't declared the `@filename` array).
- `push(@filename, $_)` is doing nothing useful as you haven't set `$_` to anything (so it contains `undef`).
- The first argument to `split()` is a regex. So `split(/,/, ...)` rather than `split(',', ...)` (your version works but mine is, I think, clearer).
- Why split `$line` twice into two separate arrays? All you really want is `my ($name, $ip) = split(/,/, $line)`.
- If you use `qq(...)` instead of `"..."` to build the string in your `system()` call then you can remove all of the `\` that make it look too noisy.
- Careful indentation will make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The following demo code demonstrates how you could alter your code to make it more readable.

You can use [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system) call with a command stored in a variable and arguments stored in an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $fname = "ssg_test1.csv";

open my $fh, '<', $fname
        or die "Couldn't open $fname";

my @fields = split(',',<$fh>);

while( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        my($name,$ipaddr) = split(',',$_);
        say "$name :: $ipaddr";
        #system($cmd,@args);
}

close $fh;

exit 0;
```

For example system call could look like following

```
my $cmd = 'mgmt_cli';
my @args = qw(
    add generic-object 
    create com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiGatewayPlain 
    name $name 
    ipaddr $ipaddr 
    thirdPartyEncryption True 
    osInfo.osName Gaia
    vpn.create com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiVpn
    vpn.owned-object.vpnClientsSettingsForGateway.create com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiVpnClientsSettingsForGateway
    vpn.owned-object.vpnClientsSettingsForGateway.owned-object.endpointVpnClientSettings.create com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiEndpointVpnClientSettingsForGateway
    vpn.owned-object.vpnClientsSettingsForGateway.owned-object.endpointVpnClientSettings.owned-object.endpointVpnEnable True
    vpn.owned-object.ike.create com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiIke
    vpn.owned-object.sslNe.create com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiSslNetworkExtender
    vpn.owned-object.sslNe.owned-object.sslEnable False
    vpn.owned-object.sslNe.owned-object.gwCertificate defaultCert
    vpn.owned-object.isakmpUniversalSupport True
);

system($cmd, @args);
```

Recommendation: please find some time for reading free book [Modern Perl](http://www.nylxs.com/docs/modern-perl-fourth-edition_p1_0.pdf) to improve your [Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/) programming style